# Django Login Form- Logs into the dashboard 2nd time

Tags: python, django, django-login

I've a login form. Whenever I sign into it for the first time, it asks me the username and password again, without showing me inavlid username and password. But when I login again with the same username and password it logs in perfectly. How is it possible?

Here is my code:-

```
{% extends "base1.html" %}
    {% block header %} 
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="content-wrap">
                <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
                <form action ="." method = POST class="form-signin" class="well form-inline">
                    <h3 class="form-signin-heading"></h3>
                    {% csrf_token %}    
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <input type = "submit" value = "login" class="btn btn-primary">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div><!--end of wrap-->

    {%endblock%}
```

**My urls.py file**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
from django.conf.urls import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'login', login,kwargs = {'template_name' : 'auth/login.html'}, name = 'xyz_login'),
    url(r'logout', logout,kwargs = {'template_name' : 'auth/logout.html'}, name = 'xyz_logout'),
)
```

**settings.py file**

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  = '/dashboard/'
LOGIN_URL           = '/login/'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('modules.data.backend.MyModelBackend',)
```

**backend.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class MyModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self,username=None, password=None):
        return super(MyModelBackend,self).authenticate(username=username,password=password)
```

Comment: Would require the server console output for this, so that we can debug what requests are being made.... Also Have to tried in all browser and sure that its not a cache issue ?

Comment: Yes it's not a cache issue. Have checked that. The server logs are when I try to log in for the 1st time. `[28/Apr/2014 06:49:22] "POST /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[28/Apr/2014 06:49:22] "GET /login/?next=/dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1536
`

Comment: For the 2nd time- `[28/Apr/2014 06:50:27] "POST /login/dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[28/Apr/2014 06:50:27] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11292` and it gets logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in these logs:

1st :

```
[28/Apr/2014 06:49:22] "POST /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 
[28/Apr/2014 06:49:22] "GET /login/?next=/dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1536
```

2nd :

```
[28/Apr/2014 06:50:27] "POST /login/dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 
[28/Apr/2014 06:50:27] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11292
```

The **1st time** you are doing a **POST request** to `/dashboard` url, which must be **login_required**. Hence, you get a 302 **redirect** to `/login/?next=/dashboard/`

The **2nd time you** **POST correctly** on `/login`. Hence you get logged in and redirected to `/dashboard`

**Now you will have to debug and see why the first POST request is being made to `/dashboard` rather than `/login`** ?

Comment: Thanks a lot... Have been searching for it for over 2 days. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)

    msg = None

    if request.method == "POST":

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                redirect_to = request.POST.get('next') or request.GET.get('next') or "/"
                return redirect(redirect_to)
            else:
                msg = 'Invalid credentials'
        else:
            msg = 'Error validating the form'
```

you need add

```
                redirect_to = request.POST.get('next') or request.GET.get('next') or "/"
                return redirect(redirect_to)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).