# Django ORM JOIN query

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I've 2 models

```
class ShipmentBagSealMapping(models.Model):
    bag_seal = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 255, default = 'open')
    time = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True, db_index = True)
    shipment_id = models.ForeignKey('Shipment', related_name = 'bags')



class Shipment(models.Model):
    job_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    time = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True, db_index = True)
```

I want to write a **JOIN** query which tells me the count of records in `ShipmentBagSealMapping` with `status = close` and time of `Shipment` is in range `[start_time and end_time]`.

Here' what I tried:

```
total_bags = ShipmentBagSealMapping.objects.filter(shipments__time__range = [start_time,end_time],status='close').values('bag_seal').distinct().count()
```

But it throws an error saying :-

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'shipments' into field. Choices are: bag_seal, id, shipment_id, status, time
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
total_bags = ShipmentBagSealMapping.objects.filter(shipment_id__time__range = [start_time,end_time],status='close').values('bag_seal').distinct().count()
```

See you have defined the field as `shipment_id` not `shipments`

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306953/django-login-form-logs-into-the-dashboard-2nd-time
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Django will automatically add _id in your ForeignKey, so make some change like this may help

```
class ShipmentBagSealMapping(model.Model):
bag_seal = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
status = models.CharField(max_length = 255 )
time = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True)
shipments = models.ForeignKey('Shipment', related_name = 'bags')
```